# Replace Javascript (Como Funciona?)

Tags: javascript

Será que teria como alguém me explicar como funciona o Replace? Estou tentando fazer a contagem da quantidade de caracteres digitados por um usuário no CEP, porém está com Mascara, e ai os campos em branco ficam com `_` (Underline). eu tentei fazer assim para remover o traço e funcionou, porém fica contando os `_`

```
var zipCodeValue = $(ZipCode).val();
zipCodeValue = zipCodeValue.replace("-","")
```

neste código acima ele remove o traço, mas contabiliza os espaços em branco com underline, ai tentei fazer assim:

```
zipCodeValue = zipCodeValue.replace("-","").replace("_","");
```

Porém ele só remove 1 Underline. também tentei fazer utilizando a variável igual esta que vi neste exemplo abaixo, mas não entendi como é escrito, Pesquisei em vários foruns e também em diversos vídeos do youtube, mas não mostra a funcionalidade. será que alguém poderia me explicar como monta e funciona este tipo de variável do Replace??? pra que serve os caracteres `/` `\` `|` `g`
a única coisa que eu acho que estou certo seria no `\` que entendo que seja para os caracteres reservados.

```
var er = /\^|~|\?|,|\*|\.|\-/g;
```

se repararem na imagem abaixo, o `-` é removido e 1 `_` também.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tá usando algum plugin ?

Comment: estou usando inputmask para fazer a mascara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu pode usar um regex:

```
zipCodeValue = zipCodeValue.replace(/[\-_]/g,"");
```

tudo que for traço ou underline ele vai remover.

As barras definem o inicio e o fim do regex, os colchetes definem um conjunto de elementos que nesse caso estão sendo representados por `\-` (traço)* e `_` (underline), o g após o fim do regex significa (global), ou seja não vai parar no primeiro underline, como tava acontecendo anteriormente.

`*` A contra-barra antes do traço serve para escapar ele, pois em um regex ele é um caractere especial.

Leia mais aqui: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Valeu Junior, deu certinho aqui :) tks